# delphi android device serial number for zebra mc930

Tags: android, delphi, mobile, honeywell, zebra-scanners

I have zebra mc930 and mc330. I'm developing android program with delphi. I want to reach device serial number for log.

using
JStringToString(TJBuild.JavaClass.SERIAL)
is working for CK65 Honeywell but for zebra is not also zebra using android 10, honeywell android 9. What can i do?

[image]

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Android introduced a restriction from A10 onwards that non-system apps cannot access the device serial number: https://developer.android.com/about/versions/10/privacy/changes#non-resettable-device-ids

Some OEMs do offer the ability to retrieve the serial number through proprietary APIs, for example Zebra devices expose what they call OEMInfo.  All of the samples around it are based on Java or Xamarin though, I can't point you to an example in delphi

Comment: thank you for answer. I may use android id for my programs log.